# AngularJS Core vs. Angular JS Nuget packages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This should be a stupid question, but I can't for the life of me find any explanation of this.

In Nuget there are two packages that looks like the main-packages: [AngularJS Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Core/1.3.8) and [Angular JS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/1.3.8). The former have *The AngularJS Team* as authors, just like the rest of the other angular modules, and ~200k downloads. The later have different authors *Fitzchak Yizcaki, Dov Landau* not seen anywhere else, and the id of the package is not in the same format as the other packages but this has ~350k downloads.

Now, by looking at the dependencies on the other packages, we see that they refer to AngularJS.Core so we now that this is what we want. I assume.

But what is the other package, and why does is almost have twice the downloads?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It turns out that *Angular JS* package is the original main package, and that all these other modules including *AngularJS Core* are the result of [an initiative to partition the angular framework](http://www.johnpapa.net/modular-angularjs-nuget-packages/).

Darn confusing start when one is about to get his hands dirty, some explanation about this in the description of the packages would be nice.

Answer (score 38):

Late to the party here, but I'm sure this will benefit someone in the future:

[image]