# what is the difference between installing angular js and angular js core via nuget?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this on my packages.config, I wonder whats the difference between both, should I uninstall any?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.3.15" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.3.15" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Route" version="1.3.15" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AngularJS.Sanitize" version="1.3.15" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.11.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Core vs. Angular JS Nuget packages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756719/angularjs-core-vs-angular-js-nuget-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `angularjs` is a full suite of angular.js scripts. It is owned and maintained by a user named [fitzchak](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/1.3.15).

`angularJS.Core` is owned and maintained by [The AngularJS Team](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Core/), which includes Scott Hanselman, John Pappa, and Renata Fuller.

Aside from the project maintainers, which may be important for future updates to the packages, the files included are the same.  Both `angularjs` and `angularJS.Core` include the base `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`.  The other optional files `AngularJS.Route` and `AngularJS.Sanitize` correspond to the appropriate official modules, if you use the separated packages.

Ultimately, the first two packages are identical, but it won't make any difference, until one is updated and the other isn't, which could lead to unexpected behavior.  You should remove the extra package; Since `angularJS.Core` is a Dependency of the other optional files, you will either want to stick with `angularjs` and have all the scripts, even ones you don't use, or `angularJS.Core` and the optional scripts which you plan to use only.

Answer (score 2):

The AngularJS framework encompasses multiple modules including routing, sce and some other.

The `angularjs` package is a consolidated package for all of these packages, whereas packages released under `angularjs.*` are for specific modules. `AngularJS.Core` is the core module.

In case you want flexibility in terms of what module to use, use the `angularjs.*` packages.

Both are not required.